# RabbitQM multiple queues or single queue?

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, amqp

I started to use RabbitMQ to manage my Hapi.js RESTful API requests. The basic flow is that once the node server receives a request, the handler will send parameters to a queue and the worker will consume it and then send the result back to another queue which point to the corresponding handler. Finally the handler will reply the result to client. Now I have two options to design the framework.

1.Create one queue for each consumer. Once the queue is filled with a request, the consumer will process it.

2.Have only one queue for all the consumers. The consumers will grab tasks from the queue by some key words.

The only reason I consider option 2 is memory costing when creating a queue.

Does anyone have experience? Which option should I take?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a answer from RabbitMQ community:

It depends on how many queues you expect to have but a single queue has long been considered an anti-pattern.
Don't do it.

Consistent hashing or another hashing algorithm can be used to map N consumers to M queues but 
not every system can accept "mismapped" values when either N or M changes.